# ScrollView not responding with LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a ScrollView but it does not work. It is not responding. I was wondering if anyone can find something suspicious in my xml file.

I do have other xml files using the same Android tool and they are working just fine.

Here's my code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="alias"
            android:id="@+id/alias"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="date_of_post"
            android:id="@+id/date_of_post" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="comment"
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: If you want it to scroll the LinearLayout needs to be wrap_parent.  If it fills the screen it will start scrolling

Comment: I don't see any issue with the codes, It should work properly. Are you inflating this view some where else or you are using as content view for activity?

Comment: The DDMS View Hierarchy dump is priceless for layout issues like this.  I'd suggest dumping the view hierarchy in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="alias"
        android:id="@+id/alias"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="date_of_post"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alias"
        android:id="@+id/date_of_post" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="comment"
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date_of_post"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Then you just don't have enough text to fill the view.  Its not going to scroll unless its full

Comment: Scratch that I just remembered you don't want a LinearLayout to be the child of a scroll view.  Check my edit

Comment: actually I'm sure it should be working because I have many items on my list. I'm starting to believe there is something working with my layout.

Comment: Post the entire layout I'll spot it if I get a minute

Comment: well a friend just solved my problem. I was not looking at the right layout... Thanks for your time and for your help Jasz !

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see anything wrong in your xml. My suggestion is you should look at the display, did your textviews go over the screen or not? cuz if it the screen, there wont be anything to scroll. Hope it help ^^